# Check if image can be loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a page with lots of images on it. My images are loaded from an external server. Usually this server it's loading tooooooooo slow, so my page stay loading until the external server starts running again. I want to put a blank image loaded from mine when the external server is down.

Is there any method to do something like this?

```
if ($("img").load=false) {
 $("img").src="cantload.png";
}
```

Thank you so much, in advance!

Comment: onerror event should make it

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jquery, and this piece of code happens before the binding of the image.

```
$("img").error(function() {
    alert("Could not load image");
});
```

If not, then you could do something like this, which will always work, but will need to be on each image:

```
<img src="image.gif" onerror="alert('Could not load image.')">
```

Comment: Thank you, i'm checking it!

Comment: @MMPP ya, that needs to be checked for fully cross broswer compatibility. Usually, bind it before setting attribute src of image. EDIT: or use inline script as gillyb is doing

Comment: The problem prospers. The image is loading continuously.

Comment: Yep, that is right. I wrote that it will only work if the image binding happens after that piece of code, or you can do it inline.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to activate this function after the elements are already in the DOM, you can use something like this.

```
var defaultSource = 'cantload.png';

$('img').each(function() {
    var originalSource = $(this).attr('src');

    $(this)
        .attr('src', defaultSource)
        .error(function(){
            $(this).attr('src', defaultSource );
        })
        .attr('src', originalSource);
});
```

The above code would bind the inner function to handle the images' loading errors, and then make them all reload. The pictures that are already reloaded won't be actually reloaded again, but those with the errors will trigger the error handler and change the `source attribute` into `cantload.png`

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/a9rXp/)

Comment: Modifying an image src to the existing src doesn't work in all browsers. Some are smart enough to realize this, and won't trigger the actual 'load' event again.

Comment: if i remember it, on chrome (version???) you have to set a empty src before reaffecting original src

Comment: But setting empty src is also a bad practice, since in some browsers might set a request to the website for nothing. The right way to do it in this case is probably set an image you know exists, something like 'blank.gif' which is just white or transparent, and then switch it the image you're not sure of..

Comment: The problem prospers. The image is loading continuously.

Comment: Thank you! But the problem is the same. you can try by loading this image: http://piercam.cofairhope.com/jpg/image.jpg . @Itay

Comment: Updated answer according to the comments and added a working fiddle (checked on FF23, Chrome 29 and IE 8+)

Comment: (you can check the full screen result) http://jsfiddle.net/a9rXp/2/embedded/result/

Comment: In the example from your fiddle, you omised to put http:// before the image adress that I shared you.

Comment: Now, when you put the correct address of image, you can see that it doesn't load.

Comment: It does work, it just take a lot of time because the server `piercam.cofairhope.com` is dead. Here's an example of a mistaken url (in the second picture) on a working server. http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/a9rXp/3/ . Also don't post so many comments, you can edit or delete old ones.